# How to save a tab group in Firefox Panorama?

Tags: firefox, panorama

I recently started using Firefox Panorama. If I create a tab group that contains, for example, my favorite Stack Exchange websites, can I save ("bookmark") this tab group for easy access if I start a new session?

Answer (score 3):

I got an answer for the firefox forum:
You can bookmark all those tabs and place them in a folder. "Bookmark This Page" and "Bookmark All Tabs" no longer show in the Bookmarks menu unless you open the Bookmarks menu via the keyboard (Alt + B). "Bookmark All Tabs" can be accessed via the right-click context menu of a tab on the tab bar.